# Why is Nusselt number principally infinite at x = 0?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

While studying heat transfer, I came across the above statement in my textbook. The conditions of the flow were given as:

1. Laminar flow
2. Incompressible
3. Circular tube

The above statement seems to apply both to thermal and combined entry length problems.

Can someone explain why this is the case? I find it difficult to understand as to why heat transfer via conduction would be zero at x = 0.

Graphs for further illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find it difficult to understand as to why heat transfer via conduction would be zero at x = 0.

Although the Nusselt number represents the ratio of convective to conductive heat transfer, this is not the correct conclusion to draw in this case.

The appropriate conclusion is that convection is extremely strong at first contact between a fluid and a surface because the boundary layer thickness is essentially zero. Thus, heat transfer occurs over a very steep temperature gradient and is therefore very effective. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that explanation really helped me understand